# private member cannot accessible in child class but my below code give successful run why

Tags: java

` private member cannot accessible in child class but my below code give successful run but i know that the private member only accessible in that class where its define. parentclass(parent class) and childClass(child class) are two.

```
public class ParentClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        childClass c=new childClass();
        c.display("Hazrat Ali");
        System.out.println("My father name is:"+c.getName());

    }

}
class childClass extends ParentClass
{
    private String Name;
    public void display(String n)
    {
        Name=n;
    }
    public String  getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}**
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You're not using a private member directly, only through the class's methods.  So why would you expect there to be a problem?

Comment: The `childClass` is `package` accessible. The constructor and getter is `public` accessible. There is no private member other than the field `Name` which is accused through `getName()` which is legal.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why do you think that there'd be anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are setting name as private String :

```
 private String Name;
```

and accessing it using a public function getName() and returning its value to the caller:

```
 public String  getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
```

and as your (getter) function  getName() has a public access modifier you can 
call it using child class object:

```
 childClass c=new childClass();
    c.display("Hazrat Ali");
    System.out.println("My father name is:"+c.getName());
```

**Encapsulation / Data hiding**

To achieve encapsulation in Java −

1. Declare the variables of a class as private.
2. Provide public setter and getter methods to modify and view the variables 
   values.

**Benefits of Encapsulation**

- The fields of a class can be made read-only or write-only.
- A class can have total control over what is stored in its fields.

  Encapsulation  provide control over the data.

Answer (score 0):

making class attributes hidden from other class is called Encapsulation
 
To achieve encapsulation in Java −

```
    Declare the variables of a class as private.

     Provide public setter and getter methods to modify and view the variables 
       values.
```

what you done is field name is accessible in class only as you accessed variable by getter function i assumed that you learned but using java built-in class 
for working with private data you should have getter and setter function

```
  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }




    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

private members cannot be accessible directly from outside the class but can be accessed using getters and setters and here you are doing the same. You are using getter to access the Name variable so nothing is wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

You're *not* accessing a private variable of `childClass` from `parentClass` - you're calling public methods that access private variables of `childClass`. There's absolutely nothing wrong with a public method using one of its class's private variables.

Also, your `main` method is static, so it isn't associated with any particular instance of `ParentClass`. You could've just easily put this method in `childClass` (or some other class - it makes no difference whatever). That being said, it's not strictly accurate to say that you're actually accessing it *from* `ParentClass` - that class really doesn't have anything to do with anything here.